# Weird subscript name in output

Tags: output-formatting, variable-definitions, subscript

One of my first times using mathematica, I'm getting a weird Subscript(1,0) output when I try to solve a derivative.  What is going on and how can I fix this?

[image: Subscript output]

Comment: Try to avoid Subscript until you are more comfortable with Mathematica. For instance, try `D[Subscript[c, t], c]`. Just use `cf,nf` as variable names instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is, that the nicely formatted subscripts in the frontend looking like $c_f$ are no "real" variables, but are represented as `Subscript[c,f]`. You can see that, if you use `FullForm` on one of those subscript-lookalikes.

Therefore, your code does end up trying to create the derivative of the *Mathematica*-function `Subscript`, but of course there is no such thing. This is why you are left with that result.

**Solution:**

Exchange any subscript with a more straightforward representation, e.g. (as suggested by Marius): `cf` instead of `Subscript[c,f]` etc.

Comment: Or use the Notation package