# total differential of a subscripted variable

Tags: subscript, differentials

During use of sub-scripted variables, I came across the following issue

`Dt[Subscript[x,0]]`

gives

[image: output]

1. Why is mathematica treating x and not x$_0$ as the variable?
2. What is (1,0) Subscript$^{(1,0)}$ ?
3. Later I wanted to `TagSet` Dt[x$_0$] to dx$_0$ (Dt[x$_0$] appears as part of some other expression). But because of the above, a tagset on x$_0$ doesn't work

Comment: TIP: never use `Subscript`s.

Comment: Related: point 3 of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999).  Also related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77866/weird-subscript-name-in-output,...

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the system options to exclude [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript) from being differentiated. The relevant option:

```
SystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions"]
```

> {"DifferentiationOptions" -> {"ExcludedFunctions" -> {Hold, HoldComplete, 
>        Less, LessEqual, Greater, GreaterEqual, Inequality, Unequal, Nand, Nor, 
>        Xor, Not, Element, Exists, ForAll, Implies, Positive, Negative, 
>        NonPositive, NonNegative, Replace, ReplaceAll, ReplaceRepeated}}}

Adding [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript):

```
With[
    {
    new = Append[Subscript] @ OptionValue[
        SystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions"],
        "DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions"
    ]
    },
    SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions" -> "ExcludedFunctions" -> new]
];
```

Then, [`Dt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dt) will no longer try to differentiate your subscripted variable:

```
Dt[Subscript[x, 0]]
```

> Dt[Subscript[x, 0]]

Comment: Is this a responsible answer in your opinion Carl? If newcomers (who often tend to always use `Subscript` in the non-indended way) search and see this answer, don't you think you are doing them a disservice?

Comment: Also, this answer does not in fact answer either questions 1 or 2. ("Question" 3 is not actually a question).

Answer (score 0):

The total differential `Dt[f[x,0]]` is `Dt[x]f^(1,0)[x,0]`, or in `InputForm`,

```
Dt[x]*Derivative[1, 0][f][x, 0]
```

The two variable function `Subscript[x,y]` is being treated no differently to any other two variable function `f[x,y]`. In particular, the `(1,0)` superscript means 1st derivative w.r.t. first variable.

For a while I have been using the following to define subscripted (or other composite) variables that can be copy-pasted and entered in formatted form, but I'm not sure how robust this is:

```
FormatSymbol[var_, rep_String] := Module[{b, s1, s2},
  b = ToString[FullForm[Apply[MakeBoxes, MakeExpression[rep, StandardForm]]]];
  s1 = SymbolName[var] <> "/:MakeBoxes[" <> SymbolName[var] <> ",StandardForm]:=" <> b;
  ToExpression[s1];
  s2 = "MakeExpression[" <> b <> ",StandardForm]:=HoldComplete[" <> SymbolName[var] <> "]";
  ToExpression[s2];
  Column[{s1, s2}]
]
```

Usage example:

```
FormatSymbol[ x0, "xsub0" ];
```

where  `xsub0`  is supposed to be typed as `x` subscripted with `0` (i.e., `x Ctrl_ 0` , but I can't type that here).

To clear the above formatting of symbol x0,

```
UnformatSymbol[ x0 ];
```

where

```
UnformatSymbol[var_] := Module[{b, s1, s2},
  b = ToString[FullForm[MakeBoxes[var // DisplayForm][[1]]]];
  s1 = SymbolName[var] <> "/:MakeBoxes[" <> SymbolName[var] <> ",StandardForm]=.";
  ToExpression[s1];
  s2 = "MakeExpression[" <> b <> ",StandardForm]=.";
  ToExpression[s2];
  Column[{s1, s2}]
]
```

The return values for the above functions are, of course, just to see what's going on.

Comment: Why do you use strings? Just use something like `fs[v_, d_]:=With[{boxes = MakeBoxes[d, StandardForm]},
v/:MakeBoxes[v, StandardForm]:=boxes;
MakeExpression[boxes, StandardForm]:=HoldComplete[v]
]`